# Is there any way to execute something in react-native when app is closed?

Tags: react-native

I want to develop an app which notifies user whether it rains or not when they're out.

For that, I determined to utilize push notification service.

Therefore, I need to execute something in ***particular time*** (e.g., sending request to API server) ***when app is closed***.

Are there any modules or packages in react-native?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [react-native-background-actions](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions) or [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.